# .NET DSACryptoServiceProvider Key Sizes

Tags: c#, .net, security, public-key-encryption, public-key

I want to use a 2048 bit DSA key, and I am using a .NET `DSACryptoServiceProvider`.  I was having trouble loading the key parameters into a .NET `DSAParameters` object, so I wrote the following code to output the valid key sizes for a `DSACryptoServiceProvider`:

```
DSACryptoServiceProvider sampleDSA = new DSACryptoServiceProvider();
Console.Write("----- DSA LEGAL KEY SIZES -----\n");
foreach (KeySizes ks in sampleDSA.LegalKeySizes)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Min: " + ks.MinSize.ToString());
  Console.WriteLine("Max: " + ks.MaxSize.ToString());
}
```

There is only one `KeySizes` object in the array, and the ouput is as follows:

```
----- DSA LEGAL KEY SIZES -----
Min: 512
Max: 1024
```

Is there any way to have a 2048 bit key using a `DSACryptoServiceProvider`?  Using a 1024 bit key is not an option.

**----EDIT-----**

I have enumerated the `LegalKeySizes` for all .NET `CryptoServiceProvider` classes that deal with Digital Signatures.  The results are as follows.

```
System.Security.Cryptography.DSACryptoServiceProvider
Min: 512
Max: 1024

System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider
Min: 384
Max: 16384

System.Security.Cryptography.ECDsaCng
Min: 256
Max: 384
Min: 521
Max: 521
```

What I meant to ask was: Is there a way to tweak this to use a 2048 bit key using a `DSACryptoServiceProvider`, or am I locked into the 512-1024 bit range?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the legal key sizes output you posted, the .NET implementation will not work with more than 1024 bits.

Perhaps some other crypto provider would work?  I've used the Bouncycastle (www.bouncycastle.org) .NET provider before for things that .NET's provider cannot do.

Comment: As posted by @bartonjs, the .NET Framework 4.6.2 adds support for FIPS 186-3 Digital Signature Algorithm (DSA). (see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/02/announcing-net-framework-4-6-2/ )

Answer (score 4):

.NET 4.6.2 added DSACng, which is a FIPS-186-3 compatible implementation of DSA.  DSACryptoServiceProvider is limited to FIPS-186-1 (which had a 1024-bit key limit).

Other than constructing the object, you should avoid depending on the concrete type, instead just using members on the DSA base class.

```
using (DSA dsaPublicPrivate = new DSACng(2048))
using (DSA dsaPublic = new DSACng())
{
    dsaPublic.ImportParameters(dsaPublicPrivate.ExportParameters(false));

    byte[] signature = dsaPublicPrivate.SignData(data, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256);
    bool isValid = dsaPublic.VerifyData(data, signature, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256);

    ...
}
```